# smalltalk texteditor widget print new line

Tags: return, smalltalk, text-editor

I am using Cincom VisualWorks and using the TextEditor widget.  I am able to write data to this widget but for the life of me, I am unable to print new line (or carraige return) characters.  Using "cr" as in for "Transcript: cr" doesn't work in this widget.  Does anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 2):

There is a method #setText:, and depending on the system you might need CR and LF:

```
myTextEditorWidget setText: 'line1', Character cr asString, Character lf asString, 'line2'.
```

if the #setText: method is not defined yet you can do so by adding this as an accessor to the class; say you told the UIBuilder that the text-field has name myText, then you can add the method:

```
myTextEditorWidget myText: 'line1', Character cr asString, Character lf asString, 'line2'.
```

Comment: In VW there is also a useful method withCRs: `'line1\line2' withCRs`